# easy way to get and print input onto window

Tags: c, ncurses, curses

I'm developing an app in C using ncurses, I want a box where I can get user input, only problem is, I can't find a way to do it that works the way I need it to.

For example, the closest ive come is the `mvwgetnstr()` routine, however this doesn't print the inputted characters back onto the window like I want it to. Ive searched around for quite a while now but I couldn't find anything.

Thanks for the help!

edit: just to clarify, I would need a routine like `mvwgetnstr()` just with the input being printed back onto the window.

Comment: Try switching on echo.  The characters will only show if echo is on. https://linux.die.net/man/3/echo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [**`getstr`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getstr.3x.html) manual page tells you:

> Characters  input  are  echoed  only  if [**`echo`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-echo_noecho) is currently on.  In that
>   case, backspace is echoed as deletion of the previous character  (typically a left motion).

and the [**`echo`**](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_inopts.3x.html#h3-echo_noecho) manual page gives you more information:

> The  echo  and  noecho routines control whether characters typed by the
>          user are echoed by [getch(3x)](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters) as they are typed.   Echoing  by  the  tty
>          driver  is  always  disabled,  but  initially **`getch`** is in **echo** mode, so
>          characters typed are echoed.  Authors of most interactive programs prefer  to do their own echoing in a controlled area of the screen, or not
>          to echo at all, so  they  disable  echoing  by  calling  **`noecho`**.   [See
>          [curs_getch(3x)](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/curs_getch.3x.html#h3-Reading-characters)  for  a  discussion  of how these routines interact with
>          **`cbreak`** and **`nocbreak`**.]

The ncurses manual page advised **[initializing](https://invisible-island.net/ncurses/man/ncurses.3x.html#h3-Initialization)** it with **`noecho`**; your program can turn that off (or on), at any time.